# .Net: how to keep references to "grandparent" projects lean and clean?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, projects-and-solutions, solution

It seems that I came across some 
Imagine a .net solution (in MSVS wording) (C#, webapi, mvc in my case, but I think it should not matter) with plenty of projects, organized as:

p1 -- class library

p2 -- class library, referencing p1 (add reference --> p1)

p3 -- class library

If I want to use p2 in p3, I'd add reference to p2 in p3, this is clear. Now, from my previous experiences (C++, Java) in such a model (referencing libraries or projects), this would mean that in p3 I have access to p1, so I can use p1's functionality. Seems that this is not the case in .net solution.

I can imagine various reasons of doing so, however it really clogs solution map when I try to draw all dependencies. Here is an example of a small solution with just 7 projects:

[image: Direct links to grandparents]

Hence is my question -- is there a way to keep dependencies lean&clean like following (same picture as above, but without direct links to "grandparents"):

[image: Lean and clean dependencies]

Thanks!